# MySQL query, create table with variable

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you include a variable into a create table query(.sql file)?  I have tried everything to my knowledge, but it simply sets the @variable name itself as the table name instead of the actual variable.

(I.e it sets @preset as the name instead of "cart_")

```
SET @Preset='cart_'; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `@preset,Customer` (....
```

Comment: You use `prepare` and `exec`.  However, in most cases, this action suggests a poor database design.  You should probably have the prefix as a column in the table and store everything in one table.

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic sql. To do this, you are going to have to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Try something like:

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',CONCAT('cart_',customer), ..;
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```